# Crenshaw's "Let's Build a Compiler": Transcription to C and x86 Assembler?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, x86, pascal

I am trying to work through Jack Crenshaw's excellent compiler programming tutorial "Let's Build a Compiler" and have bumped into two hurdles. First the code is written in Pascal, a great language for which I have both respect and fondness from a brief exposure to it in the mid 1980s, but which I have not touched since. I currently program mostly in C.

The other hurdle is that the generated assembler is for the Motorola 68000 line of processors. While I may be able to find a translator for it, it would be preferable if I could generate Intel x86 assembler (either Intel or AT&T style).

I can work through the code on Linux, Mac OsX or Windows 7, if it makes anything easier. I have access to all of the named operating systems.

I do not feel fully qualified to do the transcription myself. Has anybody worked this out already, or do you have other suggestions?

Any ideas, feedback or suggestions welcome.

Comment: I wrote a C/x86 conversion of Jack's code. I would read each installment as he released it, convert the code, and post it to Compuserve. I do not know if I still have that stuff. Contact me directly (my email address is in my profile) if you would like me to search through my archives. I make no promises, as that was something more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the generated code on a [68K emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:68k_emulators)—several of the entries on that page are open-source.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to target the JVM instead of a native processor. as for translating Pascal to C... it'shouldn't be *that* much of a hurdle really.

Comment: Dragging in complex frameworks is contraproductive. The goal of the tutorial is to provide insight, not be "easy".